# Node.js dynamic update Raphael path via socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs, raphael

I have a Raphael path in a web page. Is there a way to change it dynamically with data coming from a socket.io event? I'm using node.js, express, ejs and socket.io.

```
<div id="canvas" class="container-md"></div>

<script>

var nn = (data from socket.io);

window.onload = function() {
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 500, 500);
 
        var circ = paper.circle(250, 250, nn);
        circ.attr({fill: '#000', stroke: 'none'});
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. Just generate the path into the var socket = io(); event. So simple... Sorry